# Is there already an open source project which will make it possible to build plain HTML5 RIA's from FXML?

Tags: ios, html, xaml, javafx, ria

I am a windows developer with experience in WPF and Silverlight who has moved to the Mac.
The only thing I've missed on the Mac was "Expression Blend" and "Visual Studio" which both supports XAML.
Now that I found JavaFX 2 I am very sure that JavaFX will rule the desktop some time because it is platform independent.
I know that JavaFX will also run on iOS devices someday, but at the moment apple is blocking virtual machines other than JavaScript.

Wouldn't it be great to recompile FXML into HTML5?
HTML5 is able to run on all devices including iOS, Windows Phone, Android, Blackberry etc.
The fact that FXML is using CSS for styling would make it easy to build HTML5 from it.
The compiler could create code for KendoUI, jQuery, Sencha or even Zebkit.

Comment: `Now that I found JavaFX 2 I am very sure that JavaFX will rule the desktop` - No sane developer who has done anything relevant in WPF would ever, ever, EVER say that.

Comment: By the way oracle UX sucks a lot. They don't care about UX stuff, only crappy windows 3.1-like enterprise software. I would not expect JavaFX to ever, ever, EVER have the capabilities currently present in WPF 4.0.

Comment: Remember I am talking about **JavaFX 2.* !**  
In my opinion Oracle has done a great job with that release.  
It has everything an Interaction Designer like me loves.  
There is a separation between UI and logic.  
There are transitions and animations.  
One is able to embed HTML5 including JavaScript.
And there is support for CSS styling.